# GCC equivalent to VC's floating point model switch?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, compiler-options

Does GCC have an equivalent compiler switch to VC's [floating point model switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) (`/fp`)?

In particular, my application benefits from compiling with `/fp:fast` and precision is not a big deal, how should I compile it with GCC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `-ffast-math`.  On gcc 4.4.1, this turns on:

- `-fno-math-errno` - Don't set errno for single instruction math functions.
- `-funsafe-math-optimizations` - Assume arguments and result of math operations are valid, and potentially violate standards
- `-ffinite-math-only` - Assume arguments and results are finite.
- `-fno-rounding-math` - Enable optimizations that assume default rounding.  This is the default, but it could be overridden by something else.
- `-fno-signaling-nans` - Enable optimizations that can change number of math exceptions.; also default
- `-fcx-limited-range` - Assume range reduction is not needed for complex number division:
- `__FAST_MATH__` macro.

You could also enable these individually.